# How to make this query in Zend DB?

Tags: sql, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm trying to have Zend DB generate the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    US.nombre AS Cliente,
    VE.id_venta,
    VE.fecha,
    VE.total,
    ve.observacion
FROM
    usuarios AS US,
    ventas AS VE
```

I have tried the code below, but it does not work:

```
$select = $this->select();
$select->from(array('VE' => 'ventas'), array('id_venta', 'fecha', 'total', 'observacion'))
       ->from(array('US' => 'usuarios'),'ve.id_usuario');
```

Comment: I would be surprised if the native sql query works either?! What version of Zend Db are you using? Use 'join' to get data from 2 tables. What errors do you get? Take a look... zf1 http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.join , zf2 http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$select = $this->select();
$select->from(array('US' => 'usuarios'), array('US.nombre as Cliente'))
       ->from(array('VE' => 'ventas'), array('VE.id_venta', 'VE.fecha', 'VE.total', 'VE.observacion'));
```

This gives me the following output:

```
SELECT `US`.`nombre` AS `Cliente`, `VE`.`id_venta`, `VE`.`fecha`, `VE`.`total`, `VE`.`observacion` FROM `usuarios` AS `US` INNER JOIN `ventas` AS `VE`
```

Comment: Query is different. But I think result is same.

Comment: Thanks for help me.. +1